# can a node act as server and client?

Tags: ros, ros-service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can a node act as a server by advertising a service and at the same time act as a client by calling some other service?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245529/can-a-node-act-as-server-and-client??/) by [xhsio](https://answers.ros.org/users/27202/xhsio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2016-10-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sure. You need to make sure, though, that the logic in your implementation is solid and you don't somehow block yourself.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xhsio](https://answers.ros.org/users/27202/xhsio/) on 2016-10-13**:
Thanks mig..:)